# Rails3 performance is slower than Rails2 - any solution to improve performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on upgrading an application from Rails 2.3.4 to Rails 3.0.7 and noticed that the performance of Rails 3 is slower(taking twice the time of Rails2) especially because of Active record.
Is there any way to improve the performance.

Ruby version :  1.8.7

I did some basic benchmarks in my Rails console and here is the output.

Rails 3.0.7

```
Benchmark.measure { 25.upto(300){|i| u = User.find_by_id(i); p u.username if u}}
#<Benchmark::Tms:0xb5cbfd80 @cutime=0.0, @label="", @stime=0.0199999999999996, @real=0.61863899230957, @utime=0.220000000000002, @total=0.240000000000002, @cstime=0.0>
```

Rails 2.3.4

```
Benchmark.measure { 25.upto(300){|i| u = User.find_by_id(i); p u.username if u}}

#<Benchmark::Tms:0xb5edd324 @cutime=0.0, @label="", @stime=0.0300000000000002, @total=0.150000000000001, @real=0.467315912246704, @utime=0.120000000000001, @cstime=0.0>
```

In Rails 2 it takes around 0.46 seconds to find 275 records and print their username whereas in Rails 3 took 0.61 seconds.

Comment: Copy-paste logs and bechmarks results

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Thanks for the response, I noticed that the performance down is because of ActiveRecord.

Comment: @mikhailov I did a basic benchmarks and updated my question.

Comment: how much time to do run the benchmarks? did you turn off DB query cache?

Comment: use order by random and SQL_NO_CACHE to sure that cache is not use.

Comment: do you use **mysql2** gem? what's the MySQLD version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

anyway, what is purpose of the question? do you want to choose the particular Rails version to use?

if you only care why Rails became slower than before, you can use Github Issues to put the bugreport to Rails core Team

Comment: Thanks for the response.
My client wants to upgrade to Rails3 at the same time they don't want the performance to go down, So first we planned to migrate a small part of the app to Rails3 and noticed that there is a major time difference.

Comment: Rails3 had a major overall code refactoring, ActiveRecord is only part works slower than 2.3 brach. Everybody knows it and prefer to do a migration based on real code, not local benchmarks